# Web app: Data management for non-programmers

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I've been working in an office and we've had some data to work with a couple of times. By that I mean hundreds of rows with sometimes very large chunks of text in each row. Say **recipes for our customers, where you'd have ID, name, category, recipe itself, time, ...**

The thing is that we need to **work with this data and edit it** quite often and I can't figure out what's the best solution. What we've been doing so far was leaving it in an SQLite database and writing a simple PHP webapp that would list the data and creating a long editing form where you'd pass the data and save it back in the database. The presentation (think Access Reports) was simple, just **dumping the data, cover it in some HTML, some Texy! (Markdown alternative) etc.**

My question is if there's some either PHP or Python tool that would **simplify** this process when we get some other data to manage, so that we don't have to develop a new app. **Something that would create a list/table of the data (well, simple with the core languages) and create an editing environment (table, forms, JavaScript validation, ...) for average joes to work with.**

It's gonna be an intranet application, so nothing overly fancy is needed. The main condition is **ease of use**.

The closest I got was with **Adminer Editor**, but not being a HC programmer myself, I didn't know very well how to bend it for our needs.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you want a web application and Python, so I think you should take a look at [web2py.](http://web2py.com/)

If you click on the link to [web2py](http://web2py.com/) then you will get a lot of information - probably too much!

To cut to the chase: If you install web2py, point it to your SQLITE database with a couple lines of python code, then you have an instant database admin web application

The result will not be beautiful, and ease of use is perhaps arguable, but the resulting web app does everything you need.  If you find that you are working with a particular database a lot, and so would like to improve the app, you can slowly add more python code to improve the look and feel and make the application more specific to the database you are using.

Django is another web application framework using python, with a very similar feature set.  IMHO it is harder to learn how to create fast and simple web apps with Django, which is why I recommend web2py.

Comment: You have to drill through that link a bit to find a discussion of the built-in database administration tool.  Django also has a similar feature.

Comment: True, Larry.  However, if you install the web2py framework then the db admin web application comes up, out of the box, and learning to use it so simple.  Personally, I find web2py a lot easier to use then Django - especially for people who do not have a strong interest in writing code all day which is why I recommend it.

Comment: ravenspoint, no argument from me.  I just started with CherryPy and find it much more pleasant (liberating) that Django (but no database administration tool).  The point I mostly wanted to make is that web2py *does* have built-in database administration even though I didn't see it mentioned on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably nothing automated that will suit all of your needs, but perhaps some can get close.

Here are a few tools/frameworks that may help:

**Lightweight:** 
 - http://www.phpscaffold.com/ - generates CRUD pages based on SQL export (**[repo](https://github.com/tute/phpscaffold)**)

**Heavyweight:** 
 - [symfony](http://symfony.com/) has an admin generator which can be found [here](http://symfony2bundles.org/).
 - [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) offers [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1103/Scaffolding)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tips, here's the summary:

While I really like when things are done for me and I don't have to waste time with it, I don't like when control is out of my hands and the tools are way too complicated for me to grasp. So while I believe all the tools mentioned will be **great** for programmers (or advanced users), I will stick to simpler (but in the end more complicated) tools that allow me to have a little more control.

I just feel more comfortable with tools where I have total control, include only one or two files (hello **jQuery**, **Nette**, **Adminer** and others) and have fun :-)

Having said that, here are the tools I've chosen after examining most of the options:

- **Adminer Editor** for very simple data management, no adjustments to the admin area
- **Flask** for personal things. I did fall in love with this awesome micro-framework. It's dead easy to use and yet so powerful. As I don't have a server with Python support, I may try Google App Engine for this.
- **Nette** + **dibi** for common intranet management apps. It does support all the things necessary and should be easy enough to create these admin apps.

So while I did choose something different than I asked for in the beginning, I value your responses and should I need more robust solutions in the future, I will gladly give them a shot.